# Why does my script still try to create my directory?

Tags: php, codeigniter, ftp

I am attempting to write a PHP script that organizes uploaded files into directories according to the date they were uploaded.  The script needs to detect whether or not the appropriate directories exists before it executes the upload.  First, it checks if the folder 'attachments/2014' exists.  If it doesn't, it's created.  Next, it checks if the folder 'attachments/2014/October" exists.  If it doesnt, create it.  Finally, it checks if the folder 'attachments/2014/October/29' exists.  If it doesnt, it's created.  Then the file is uploaded to the last folder.

For some reason, my script always tries to create the directory, even if it already exists.  It only works if the directory doesn't exist.  Not really sure why about the former.  This is CodeIgniter PHP.

```
$dtree = array(
    date('Y'),
    date('Y').'/'.date('F'),
    date('Y').'/'.date('F').'/'.date('d')
);

$this->load->library('ftp');

$this->ftp->connect();

foreach($dtree as $dir) {

    if($this->ftp->list_files('attachments/'.$dir)) === FALSE) {

        $this->ftp->mkdir('attachments/'.$dir);

    }

}
```

If the directory exists, I get the CI error saying "Unable to create the directory you have specified."

Comment: What does `list_files('attachments/'.$dir)` return exactly?

Comment: If the directory exists, it returns an array of those files.  If the directory doesn't exist, it returns false.

Comment: @ShoeLace1291 its a typo, you have an extra `)` here `('attachments/'.$dir)) <- remove this `